# Custom editor template can't infer field name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a custom editor template for DateTimeOffset:

```
@model DateTimeOffset
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model)
</div>
```

It is used via standard API:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeOffsetField)
```

I have noticed the label that gets created has text Model:

```
<label for="DateTimeOffsetField">Model</label>
```

Also, `Required` field validator refers to the generated field as "Model" in the error message:

> Please enter Model

I assume that because the internal metadata provider is no longer aware of the original model and just knows about the new DateTimeOffset model.

How should this be handled?
Is there a different overload I can use or should I use a lower-level API (e.g. `@Html.Label`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `m => m`, using the parameter instead of the `Model` property.